# Spring-Hibernate Application Integration with EJB-Hibernate Application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, ejb

I have a **EJB-Hibernate** application, and currently I am trying to integrate another application which is built in **Spring-Hibernate**.

Now the issue is, as both of them are using Hibernate, I am confused how to integrate their hibernate configs?

Again both of them use different way of writing Hibernate configs also, i.e. Spring based app uses through Spring beans and hibernate-cfg.properties file,

Whereas EJB application is doing it, a standard hibernate way (i.e. xxx-cfg.xml and xxx-hbm.xml),

So I am confused, what should be my approach? 
Any help is welcome.

---

Sorry I forgot to mention Versions -->

In EJB Application --> EJB 2.0 and Hibernate 3.1.3
& Spring Application,  Spring 3.x and Hibernate 3.2.6

And in Spring-Hibernate Application they have their own cache implementation, currently both are referring to separate datasources and separate Db-schemas.

I want to integrate them so that, both will have same db-schema (I will do that by merging their schemas i.e. adding tables,etc. to current schema) and same datasource (Here we are using JBoss to manage datasource connections through xxx-ds.xml)

EJB-Hibernate Application we have mentioned the JNDI name of this datasource, so it refers to that.
But in Spring App, they are having their separate datasource, but I can make it reference same using same JNDI name.

Please tell me, how should I do this integration?

Comment: Can you mention EJB version please ?

Comment: we are using EJB 2.0 and Spring 3.x and Hibernate 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Your information seems to be a bit confusing but I would try to gather from what you have mentioned.

When you say that you want to intergrate both applications, then apart from using a common datasource are you trying to get rid of EJB 2 in your application and use Spring instead ?
This will require migration from EJB2 to Spring. For this there are plenty of articles like [this](http://kaksles.org/2007/08/11/how-to-migrate-a-legacy-ejb-application-to-spring-and-hibernate/) one.

Or if what you want is that both the applications should exists independently but should use single schema then as you stated you can merge both schemas into one, register the datasource in JNDI. Then use can use the same datasource in both different applications. EJB2 and Spring both can use a JNDI bound datasource.

In case both applications exist independently and one of them is using hibernate second level cache ( as you mentioned) then you will have to be careful as your cache will be invalidated very often as your database will be shared between two application which can write to database. In fact in such cases it's wise only to cache **ONLY** read-only data which never changes.

Comment: Thanks Shailendra, its the second one.. i want both of them to co-exist and still use same schema and same datasource, about second level cache, I am still confused. will it result in any cache performace issues? And if yes, can I have two different datasources for same schema, so no datasource sharing...will it be a good approach..i am little doubtful about it.

Comment: If you have two applications using second level cache in a single application server then there will be one cache for each application. Each cache will be tied to the session factory used by each application. The best approach will be to use cache only for read data. Also if there are updates to a database by one application then the cache for other application is unaware of the changes. In that case you might want to invalidate the cache too often which will far outweigh the benefit of cache. So if you have any read only data then by all means use the second level cache.